# how to handle Customcell contentview width dynamically change depends on content of data while rotating screen of device in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have set content view of customcell  `autoresizingMask` property by `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;` and it works fine but when i rotate screen of device   content view width changed fine but then when i scroll table then width of contenview get changed (it take size in calculated in delegate method tableView: `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath` ).one above problem and second question is after scrolling and then rotate back to portait form from landscape, width of content view get small.

```
    preference* pref = [[preference alloc] init];
    [pref initialize];
    userInfo *mahesh=[pref getUserInfo];

    NSLog(@"index of cell******  %d",indexPath.section);

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell2";
      imTextVO *temp=[masterArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.section)];  
        CustomCell2  *cell1 =(CustomCell2 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       NSString *cellValue = [commonArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.section)]; 

        if (cell1==nil)
        {
            cell1 = [[CustomCell2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

//            UIImageView *image=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
//            
//            [cell1.contentView addSubview:image];

    //    if (temp.type==2)
    //    {
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    //        button.frame=CGRectMake(110, 45, 100,40);
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(viewAttachmentOfEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [button setTitle:@"View Attachment" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


            button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
            button.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    //        [button setTag:(indexPath.section)];
             button.tag=22;
            [cell1.contentView addSubview:button];



    }



cell1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(160+100-140, 20000.0f);
CGSize size1 = [[ArrayForActor objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];


CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(160+100, 20000.0f);
CGSize size = [cellValue sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

if (temp.type==2) {
    if ([temp.mobileNo isEqualToString:mahesh.mobileno])
    {

        if (size.width>(size1.width+180)) {
            cell1.ViewContainer.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,size.width+4 ,size1.height+50);
        }else{
            cell1.ViewContainer.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,size1.width+4+180 ,size1.height+50);
        }

        cell1.ViewContainer.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];

        cell1.dateText.frame=CGRectMake(cell1.ViewContainer.frame.size.width-140,cell1.ViewContainer.frame.origin.y ,135 ,20);




    }else{


        if (size.width>(size1.width+180)) {
            cell1.ViewContainer.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-size.width+4,0,size.width+4 ,size1.height+50);
        }else{
            cell1.ViewContainer.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-size1.width-180+4,0,size1.width+4+180 ,size1.height+50);
        }

        cell1.dateText.frame=CGRectMake(self.chatTable.frame.size.width-140,cell1.ViewContainer.frame.origin.y ,135 ,20);
         cell1.ViewContainer.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];




    }


}else{
    if ([temp.mobileNo isEqualToString:mahesh.mobileno])
    {

        if (size.width>(size1.width+180)) {
            cell1.ViewContainer.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,size.width+4 ,size.height+4+size1.height+4);
        }else{
            cell1.ViewContainer.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,size1.width+4+180 ,size.height+4+size1.height+4);
        }
        cell1.ViewContainer.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
        cell1.dateText.frame=CGRectMake(cell1.ViewContainer.frame.size.width-140,cell1.ViewContainer.frame.origin.y ,135 ,20);




    }else{

        if (size.width>(size1.width+180)) {
            cell1.ViewContainer.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-size.width-4,0,size.width+4 ,size.height+4+size1.height+4);
        }else{
            cell1.ViewContainer.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-size1.width-180-4,0,size1.width+4+180 ,size.height+4+size1.height+4);
        }

        cell1.dateText.frame=CGRectMake(self.chatTable.frame.size.width-140,cell1.ViewContainer.frame.origin.y ,135 ,20);

        cell1.ViewContainer.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

    }
}






cell1.actorLabel.frame=CGRectMake(cell1.ViewContainer.frame.origin.x+2,cell1.ViewContainer.frame.origin.y,size1.width+4,size1.height+4);
cell1.actorLabel.text=[ArrayForActor objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];




cell1.chatText.frame=CGRectMake(cell1.ViewContainer.frame.origin.x,cell1.actorLabel.frame.size.height-12, cell1.ViewContainer.frame.size.width,size.height+4+4);

UIButton *thisInviteButton = (UIButton*)[cell1.contentView viewWithTag:22];
thisInviteButton.hidden=YES;
if (temp.type==2) {
    thisInviteButton.hidden=NO;
    thisInviteButton.frame=CGRectMake((cell1.ViewContainer.frame.size.width/2)-50,size1.height, 100,40);
}else{

}


cell1.dateText.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;
cell1.chatText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

    cell1.chatText.text= cellValue;

    cell1.selectionStyle=NO;
    NSTimeInterval interval=[temp.createdDate longLongValue];
    NSDate *currentTime=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval/1000];

    NSLocale *gbLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];


    NSNumber *myDateInString=[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]*1000];
    NSTimeInterval inte=[myDateInString longLongValue];
    NSDate *todayTime=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:inte/1000];
NSString * todayString = [[todayTime description] substringToIndex:10];
    NSString *messageDate=[[currentTime description] substringToIndex:10];
    if ([todayString isEqualToString:messageDate]) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        NSString *formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"hh.mm" options:0
                                                                  locale:gbLocale];

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];
        [dateFormatter setLocale:gbLocale];

       cell1.dateText.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime]]; 

    }else {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        NSString *formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"dMMMyy,hh.mm" options:0
                                                                  locale:gbLocale];

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];
        [dateFormatter setLocale:gbLocale];
        cell1.dateText.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime]];
    }


    return cell1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to directly answer based on your code, I am just going to give you a couple of advises:

1. Keep the `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` as clean as possible. If you have heavy calculations to do, do it before actually `[table reloadData]`. Otherwise you are going to give your user a bad experience, because each time he scrolls the `UITableView`, something heavy is being calculated.
2. If the calculations for getting the final size of the cell are heavy (complex `UITableViewCell` with multiple childs), do them before reloading the table. Again the point here is to give the user a good experience.
3. Keep your code commented, you will thank yourself, if you pick up this project some months later.
4. Normally you are able to achieve the size you want with some auto-sizing magic on the XIB. Still, you can base your calculations for the size (see point 2) based on the `self.interfaceOrientation`, you can then store those values (portrait and landscape) on a dictionary which will then be used by the `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.
5. Don't access the `UITableViewCell's` properties directly. Instead create a method called (for example..) `- (void)updateWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)cellInformation`. This way you decouple your code, creating more independent, and cleaner, components. In this `cellInformation` you could pass all the data your cell needs.